# How to find the definition domain of a function with parameters?

Tags: functions

Function is:

```
f[x_] = 1/Sqrt[Log[a, x - 1]]
```

The base of the logarithm contains parameter a, which means that in the process of manual calculation, a needs to be classified and discussed, in two cases: a>1 and 0<a<1. The result calculated using the following code is incorrect.

```
In[27]:= FunctionDomain[f[x], x]

Out[27]= 
x > 1 && Log[a] != 0 && Log[-1 + x] != 0 && Log[a] Log[-1 + x] > 0
```

the correct answer is:

```
if a>1,x>2
if 1>a>0,1<x<2
```

Comment: And your question is...? You can report the behavior to Wolfram Support if you'd like, but I am not sure what answer you seek in this forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "correct" answer follows with `Reduce`

```
FunctionDomain[f[x], x] // Reduce[#, x] &
(*(Log[a] < 0 && 1 < x < 2) || (Log[a] > 0 && x > 2)*)
```

Comment: Make the argument of `Reduce` `a` instead of `x` to get the result the OP wants.

Comment: In[5]:= FunctionDomain[{f[x]}, x] // Reduce[#, a] &

Out[5]= (1 < x < 2 && 0 < a < 1) || (x > 2 && a > 1)

Comment: @BillWatts OP 's correct answer contains parameter `a` at the first place